# assembly multiply two 16 bit program using 68hc11

Tags: assembly

I need to Write a program that will

- multiply a pair of 16-bit numbers stored at {M, M+1} and {N, N+1} and store the resulting 32-bit product at {P, P+1,P+2, P+3}.
- multiply a pair of 16-bit numbers stored at {M, M+1} and {N, N+1} and
  store the resulting 32-bit product at {P, P+1,P+2, P+3}.
- Everything is stored in “MSB at lowest address” order, i.e. (P) would
  be the highest byte of the product and (P+3) would be the lowest
  byte.
- Arrange for M to live at $200-$201, N at $202-$203, and P at
  $210-$213.
- Hint: because the HC11’s MUL instruction is 8-bit only, use the
  partial products method.
- Test your solution with each of the following cases and give your
  resulting 32-bit answer:
- Case 1: M=$4B18 and N=$71C9
- Case 2: M= N=$8FED

Ok so I found the below example code for multiplying two 32 bit numbers together.

I need to convert the code to the HC11's version of assembly and then correct it to multiply a 16 bit instead of a 32 bit number...

The mov should be changed to LD for the 68hc11 I believe and then ?

```
.model small

.data
        mult1 dw 2521H
              dw 3206H
        mult2 dw 0A26H
              dw 6400H
        ans   dw 0,0,0,0

.code
        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax

;       LEA SI,ans

        mov ax,mult1
        mul mult2
        mov ans,ax
        mov ans+2,dx

        mov ax,mult1+2
        mul mult2
        add ans+2,ax
        adc ans+4,dx
        adc ans+6,0

        mov ax,mult1
        mul mult2+2
        add ans+2,ax
        adc ans+4,dx
        adc ans+6,0

        mov ax,mult1+2
        mul mult2+2
        add ans+4,ax
        adc ans+6,dx

        mov ax,4C00h
        int 21h
end
```

Comment: Why downvote? I am asking how to turn assembly code into code for HC11.  Pretty straightforward.

Comment: I didn't vote, but you just dumped a piece of code from somewhere and essentially said "Here, translate this for me". The x86 instruction set reference manual [is freely available](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), and I'm sure the 68HC11 one is too. So what specifically did you not find a suitable 68HC11 instruction (or combination of instructions) for?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this back in 2004. Hope it helps:

```
************************************************************************************************
* This library is used to extend the HC11's math capabilities                                  *
************************************************************************************************ 

MULU_16_16: PSHD               ; The HC11 has an 8-bit CPU, and so cannot deal with 16-bit
           PSHD               ; multiplication. MULU_16_16 takes two 16-bit numbers and
           LDAA  $09,SP       ; multiplies them together, placing the 32-bit result in 
           LDAB  $07,SP       ; the stack space where the two operands once occupied.
           MUL                ; This routine doesn't need any static variables, but it
           STD   $02,SP       ; does use 10 bytes of stack space, including the call to
           LDAA  $09,SP       ; the sub, and all parameter passing. A call to this sub
           LDAB  $06,SP       ; would look like this:
           MUL                ; LDD   Operand1    ; I used D to illustrate, but this should
           ADDB  $02,SP       ; PSHD              ; also work using an index register, or a
           ADCA  #0           ; LDD   Operand2    ; MOVW instruction. Placing values on the
           STD   $01,SP       ; PSHD              ; stack before the call is passing factors.
           LDAA  $08,SP       ; JSR   MULU_16_16  ; Call the sub.
           LDAB  $07,SP       ; PULD              ; Most significant word of product.
           MUL                ; PULD              ; Least significant word of product.
           ADDB  $02,SP       
           ADCA  $01,SP       ; READ THIS DAMMIT! You MUST re-adjust the stack after calling 
           STD   $01,SP       ; MULU_16_16 even if you aren't interested in the result.
           LDAA  $08,SP       ; What's more, you MUST PLACE four bytes on the stack before
           LDAB  $06,SP       ; calling MULU_16_16. If you do not do either of these things,
           MUL                ; your program will get a nice surprise when you try to RTS
           ADDB  $01,SP       ; next. Remember, this function modifies values on the stack
           ADCA  #0           ; that were placed there BEFORE the return address from the JSR
           STD   $00,SP       ; that called it. 
           PULD               ; Destroy the stack space we created at the beginning of this 
           STD   $04,SP       ; sub.
           PULD
           STD   $04,SP
           RTS


MULU_32_32:LDD   $08,SP       ; Here we go... 32-bit by 32-bit multiply. Ready for loads of
           PSHD               ; technical detail? Here we take advantage of the routine we
           LDD   $06,SP       ; just wrote: MULU_16_16. We not only use the sub directly, but
           PSHD               ; also extend its algorithm. We need a 64-bit product (R), from
           JSR   MULU_16_16   ; two 32-bit factors (Q, P). We use the property:
           LDD   $0C,SP       ; R=(Pu*Qu*2^32)+(Pu*Ql*2^16)+(Pl*Qu*2^16)+(Pl*Ql)
           PSHD               ; to extend the reach of the HC11's puny 8-bit multiply. Also
           LDD   $08,SP       ; like the above routine, this one doesn't use any static 
           PSHD               ; memory space for operands or results. The calling procedure
           JSR   MULU_16_16   ; is similar:
           LDD   $0E,SP       ; LDD   Operand1(LSW) ; The stacking method is a little weird
           PSHD               ; PSHD                ; for people used to programming big-
           LDD   $0E,SP       ; LDD   Operand1(MSW) ; endian CPUs, the LSW of the operand is
           PSHD               ; PSHD                ; PSH'd before the MSW. It will be pulled
           JSR   MULU_16_16   ; LDD   Operand2(LSW) ; off in a logical order, however. Again,
           LDD   $00,SP       ; PSHD                ; D was used to illustrate, but the
           ADDD  $04,SP       ; LDD   Operand2(MSW) ; parameter passing could be done with
           STD   $04,SP       ; PSHD                ; MOVW's.
           LDD   $02,SP       ; JSR   MULU_32_32    ; Call the sub
           ADCB  $07,SP       ; PULD                ; Most significant word of product
           ADCA  $06,SP       ; PULD                ; Second most significant word of product
           STD   $06,SP       ; PULD                ; Third most significant word of product
           LDD   $08,SP       ; PULD                ; Least significant word of product
           ADCB  $07,SP       ; After multiplying (Pu*Qu), (Pu*Ql) and (Pl*Qu), we begin
           ADCA  $06,SP       ; adding values so we can reclaim a little stack space. Notice 
           STD   $08,SP       ; that we haven't been PUL'ing values. The stack just keeps
           LDD   $0A,SP       ; growing. Also note that MULU_32_32 is somewhat of a cycle
           ADCB  #0           ; and stack eater. On an HC11, each MUL opcode takes 10 cycles
           ADCA  #0           ; to execute, and there are 16 MUL's for each MULU_32_32 call.
           STD   $0A,SP       ; That's 160 cycles in MUL's alone. Furthurmore, the stack use
           LDD   $04,SP       ; hits a maximum of 28 bytes. Undesirable, but it might be the
           STD   $06,SP       ; only way for an HC11 to get a 64-bit result. HC12 users have
           PULD               ; the EMUL opcode which does 16-bit by 16-bit and takes only 3 
           PULD               ; cycles to complete.
           PULD               ; This sub also carries the same warning as the one above:
           LDD   $0C,SP       ; Watch your stack carefully! Before and after the call.
           PSHD               ; 
           LDD   $0A,SP       ; 
           PSHD               ; 
           JSR   MULU_16_16   ;
           LDD   $02,SP       ; 
           ADDD  $04,SP       ; 
           STD   $04,SP       ; 
           LDD   $06,SP       ; 
           ADCB  #0           ; 
           ADCA  #0           ; 
           STD   $06,SP       ; 
           LDD   $08,SP       ; 
           ADCB  #0           ; 
           ADCA  #0           ; 
           STD   $08,SP       ; 
           PULD               ; 
           STD   $00,SP       ; 
           PULD               ; 
           STD   $08,SP       ; 
           PULD               ; 
           STD   $08,SP       ; 
           PULD               ; 
           STD   $08,SP       ; 
           PULD               ; 
           STD   $08,SP       ; 
           RTS                ;
```

Comment: This is not 68HC11 compatible code as there is no SP indexed mode.  Possibly HC12?

Comment: You are correct. SP was a place-holder for some other register. X or Y in the case of HC11. But I assure you, it is valid code using Motorola's As11.